# Why doesn't root need the password to run "sudo" even when "NOPASSWD:ALL" isn't written in /etc/sudoers

Tags: linux, sudo, root

In `/etc/sudoers`, there is always:

```
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

However, the root user (with UID 0) doesn't need to enter password when they run `sudo command`.

For other users, a password is required unless their entry contains `NOPASSWD` or a previous authentication hasn't timed out:

```
user    ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
                      ^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: This is a bit weird actually. Even though you'd usually use `sudo` to run commands as UID 0, and root is already UID 0 and there's nothing to gain by stopping them, `sudo` still requires the config line for `root` to be there. Without it, it tells even root to bugger off.

Comment: Cause it is `root`. What would you gain running `sudo`  as root? "Beyond Root"? "Who watch the Watchmen?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sudo` allows users to execute commands as UID 0 (or other users) based on how it’s configured. There is no need to ask root for a password to run a command as UID 0, because it already is UID 0.

Furthermore, root can also `su` to anyone it’d like, so there’s no need to prompt for a password when executing `sudo -u user` as UID 0.

Note: I do believe there is a PAM setting that will even require root to provide a password for the target user when using `su`.

Answer (score 3):

While this is an interesting inconsistency. It would be pointless in stopping root, as root has capabilities `CAP_SETUID` and `CAP_SETGID`, so does not need sudo. It can do what ever it want.

If `sudo` is checking root, and not these capabilities, then there may be a latent-bug: root with no capabilities could escalate (I don't know I have not looked at the code, or tested).